# Visual Studio style Output Console Window in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I want to show my output that is shown in Console window in a separate screen like in Visual Studio. 
The screen shall disappear after the running of the process is over.
How can this be achieved in Eclipse IDE? 
Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: it is possible to write the console output in Workspace ,File system, Variables.

Comment: I don't know of any option for this. Output from a run in Eclipse always goes to a separate Console page in the Console view.

Comment: I have created a runnable jar of my project. I dont want to output to a txt file.I need a screen showing the messages.

Answer (score 0):

you can develop your program in Eclipse and then run it from the command window [cmd] (assuming you are using windows) using "java ..." syntax.